# 2d Range Search tree for a triangle

Tags: tree, implementation

I want to implement  2D RANGE TREES for searching given points inside a triangle effectively in O( logn^2 ).

To make things easier,I want to search no of given points which lie in right triangle  with two sides aligned parallel to x-y axis and both sides same. 
So, co-ordinates of vertices of ABC would be A(a,b) , B(a+d,b) , C(a,b+d) and it is a right triangle and AB,AC are parallel to X,Y axis respectively.

I know i can do this effectively using 2D range trees .(k-d trees O(sqrt(n)) is slow and searching for each point individually is too slow)

Can anyone show me how to implement/explain the algorithm  2D range tree to test which points lie inside above type of triangle?

Comment: DO NOT ANSWER HIS QUESTION TILL THE CONTEST IS OVER

Answer (score 0):

Either consult the [CGAL](http://www.cgal.org) library or this person's project [code](http://cgi.di.uoa.gr/~vfisikop/compgeom/Layered_Range_trees/) and [report](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1103.4521v1.pdf).

Also, the [contest](http://www.codechef.com/FEB13/problems/TRIQUERY) is still ongoing, please refrain from asking for help here until the contest is over.